# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy realizando una app de tareas con Kotlin y Android Studio. El problema es que recibo este error al pasar extras de un Intent a otro.

Me he asegurado de tener declarado el archivo al que le voy a pasar los extras en Android Manifest, me he asegurado de que el context del Intent sea correcto (en mi caso he puesto `this`) pero el problema persiste y no se de donde puede venir el error.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.listadetareas, PID: 2564
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listadetareas/com.example.listadetareas.ServicioNotificacion}:
> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> com.example.listadetareas.ServicioNotificacion cannot be cast to
> android.app.Activity
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.listadetareas.ServicioNotificacion cannot be cast to
> android.app.Activity
> at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Este es el archivo desde donde mando los extras (AnadirTareas.kt):

```
btn_añadir_tarea.setOnClickListener {
        val hora_añadir_tarea = sp_hora.selectedItem.toString()
        val minuto_añadir_tarea = sp_minuto.selectedItem.toString()

        if (titulo_añadir_tarea.isNotEmpty() && descripcion_añadir_tarea.isNotEmpty() && hora_añadir_tarea != null && minuto_añadir_tarea != null) {


            val db = DB(applicationContext);
            try {
                db.añadirTarea(applicationContext, titulo_añadir_tarea.toString(), descripcion_añadir_tarea.toString(), dia, hora_añadir_tarea, minuto_añadir_tarea )
                val intentdatostarea = Intent(this, ServicioNotificacion::class.java)

                intentdatostarea.putExtra("titulo", titulo_añadir_tarea)
                intentdatostarea.putExtra("descripcion", descripcion_añadir_tarea)
                intentdatostarea.putExtra("año", recuperar_year)
                intentdatostarea.putExtra("mes", recuperar_month)
                intentdatostarea.putExtra("dia", recuperar_day)
                startActivity(intentdatostarea)
                //val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                //startActivity(intent)

            //val notificar = Notificacion(applicationContext)
                //notificar.crearNotificacion("prueba", "prueba")


            } catch (e: Exception){
                Log.d("Error añadirTarea: ", e.toString())
            }


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Ha habido un error al crear la tarea $descripcion_añadir_tarea", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

y este es el que los recoge (ServicioNotificacion.kt). Es un servicio:

```
 override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    val title = intent?.getStringExtra("titulo")
    val descripcion = intent?.getStringExtra("descripcion")
    val anio = intent?.getStringExtra("año")!!.toInt()
    val mes = intent?.getStringExtra("mes")!!.toInt()
    val dia = intent?.getStringExtra("dia")!!.toInt()
    Log.d("Differencedays" , anio.toString())


    return START_STICKY
}
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en estas líneas

```
val intentdatostarea = Intent(this, ServicioNotificacion::class.java)
...
startActivity(intentdatostarea)
```

Estás usando `startActivity` iniciar un `Service`.

Como su nombre lo indica, este método solamente puede iniciar activities. `ServicioNotificacion` es un `Service` por lo tanto debes iniciarlo con el método `startService` o `startForegroundService` si quieres que el servicio esté en primer plano.

En tu caso no veo que estés promoviendo el servicio así que simplemente deberías llamar

```
startService(intentdatostarea)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, no sabia que existia startService.